# c++ code stops mid loop but does not throw any errors

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program designed to determine if a number is a factorial and what it is a factorial of. I.E. if the input is 39916800 the program will print "The number is 11!". The code I have below is the function that is designed to do this. The issue is that when you enter a number equal to or higher than 12! the program finishes the loop than stops running. I used print statements to show that it does not loop again, nor does it continue through the program.

```
long getFactorial(long a)
{
    long ans = -1;
    long i = 2;
    long fact = 2;

    while(fact < a)
    {
        cout << "before i++" << endl;
        i++;
        cout << "before fact*i" << endl;
        fact = fact * i;
        cout << "before print" << endl;
        cout << fact << "  " << (fact < a) << endl;
        cout << "after print" << endl;
    }

    cout << "after while";

    if(fact == a)
    {
        ans = i;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

The final loop prints,

```
before i++
before fact*i
before print
87178291200  0
after print
```

and then stops running. The code works perfectly fine for any number equal to or less than 11!. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been at this for a while and feel like I'm missing something really small.

Comment: Each integer type has a limit for maximum value it can represent. You can use long long int or for example long double.

Comment: Please provide [mre], so we could copy-paste the code, to see the described behavior.

Comment: It should work if you print an `endl` after `after while`. `endl` tells a stream to flush its buffer and without it, you might not see your characters printed immediately.

Comment: The function works correctly for me, when invoked by addition of a main() that reads `{ cout<<  " " <<getFactorial(39916800)<< " " <<  getFactorial(479001600); }`

Comment: The problem was actually further down in my program, I thought it was inside this function because I did not use `endl` after `after while` so I assumed that that was where the program was getting held up. I didn't realize that c++ doesn't print until you end the line. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wolfpack "_doesn't print until you end the line_" Isn't correct. It doesn't print until you call `flush` method on a stream. Which is done by `std::endl`, or by exiting the application, for example. You can end the line without flushing, by printing `'\n'`, instead of using `std::endl`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: On most systems, *every* newline flushes automatically *if* the output is directed to a terminal.